# unable to write to the database while uploading images

Tags: posts, images, multisite, uploads, media

I have a problem with my WP Multisite. My stable version so far is: 5.5.3 (downgraded from 5.6). With version 5.6 and later, I can't download images properly and this is for all my websites under WP. In fact, when I try to upload an image, the upload goes to the correct folder (wp-content/blogs.dir/xxx) and I get the following message

> the image post-processing probably failed because the server is busy or does not have enough resources. Uploading a smaller image may help. Suggested maximum size is 2500 pixels.

The problem is that I can't find the image in the media library. After some research I found that there were no entries for the image in the WP database (nothing in the posts or postmeta tables).

So, my question is why importing an image cannot insert the image data into the database tables? I have to mention that I have almost increased every value in the php.ini

Any help would be very appreciated

Just a quick update :
I’m using php 7.4.19
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 300
memory_limit = 2048M

Comment: I can't see the exact code at the moment but I'd guess it only creates the image entries in the database when the image processing succeeds. Can you solve that and see if that fixes the media library too? Is there anything in your server error logs or PHP error logs? (or wp-content/debug.log if you've enabled that)

Comment: I would guess the post-processing might be another plugin modifying the image like an optimisation plugin. Try disabling anything like that and test again. It could also be down to your method of downgrading if the database was updated and you just replace the files.

Comment: Hi
In the event log of my server, I find the following one:
Aborted connection 1413 to db: ‘WP’ user: ‘WPUser’ host: ‘localhost’ (Got an error reading communication packets). Nothing important for the other error log files.
I disabled all the optimation plugins and the imagemagick extension in php.
I disabled the theme and switched to the default one. 
The downgrade was done using the WP Downgrade plugin.

So i’m still stuck here and i don’t know why WP can’t write to the posts or postmeta tables.
Thank you all for your suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but in case anyone finds it, I changed my open_basedir entry in PHP.INI file to add the temp directory to it:

```
open_basedir = "C:\repos\mysite.dev.local;C:\Windows\TEMP\"
```

and this allowed the uploads to start working on my local install. NB: Note the " " around the paths.

Comment: That sounds sensible, but if your TEMP is in \Windows are you running WordPress as a local admin user? That shouldn't be necessary, and you ought to run it as something as low privileged as possible really in case it does get hacked to limit what the hacker can do.

Comment: Yes, locally as admin user. I've always simply used the "defaults" of Wordpress/MAMP/WAMP. Out of interest, how would a site on my local get hacked?

Comment: Yes fair enough it likely can't. Am surprised MAMP or WAMP run Apache as a local admin user by default though.